# how to get data from unwind in MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, aggregation-framework

I have below structured collection

SharedMediaCollection:

```
{_id:111,
imageShared:{imageId:00234,
 commentArea[{whoCommented:xyz,commentText:hi}, {whoCommented:yxz,commentText:hello}]}
 };
```

Now i am doing unwind on commentArea and trying to show whocommented and what he commented.

I did code like this...

```
Aggregation aggr = newAggregation(
        unwind("imageShared.commentArea"),
        project().andInclude("imageShared.commentArea.whoCommented"));
        AggregationResults<TestAgree1> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggr,SharedMediaCollec.class,TestAgree1.class );
        List<TestAgree1> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

here SharedMediaCollec.class is my above collection structured pojo class and
TestAgree1 is my cook up pojo which holds only CommentArea strcture as i am doing projection.

Please let me know where i am doing the mistake. I know other reference links are there but i am not able to figure it out what mistake i am doing while assigning the output type class.

Comment: The sample doc you've shown is not a valid MongoDB document. It also  does not include the commentDataDoc mentioned in your aggregation query.

Comment: While @sheilak is likely taking this a bit too literally ( no closing `}` in your structure presented, suggest a typo ), the clear problem I see is that the path `imageShared.commentDataDoc` does plainly not exist in the example document at all. Perhaps you are not really sharing what your documents really look like at all. To get a reasonable answer, you need to really show what you have. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32678129/edit) your question to include the relevant details.

Comment: @Blakes Seven, Yes its type mistake and thanks for ignoring it.
i did edited corrected it please check now, i did corrected imageShared.commentDataDoc also.

Comment: Well I may have accepted that was a typo, but the rest of what I said still remains valid. There is no such property in your sample document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mistake i did is, i didn't changed the output type of aggregation result.
After unwind the input array list type will be changed to a document type. i did created another entity object which has no list type.

Thanks all-:)

Comment: HI, i have the same problem after unwind , how to change the entity from List to Object in a Entity?